# EOL error - Escape Newline Characters in a Python String

Tags: error-handling, eol

I wish to hand chunks of text to an API. However, I cant as python wont let me handle the text if I try saving as a variable. How do I do it? Thank you

```
prompt = (f"xxxx
xxxx
xxxxx
xxxx
xxxx")
```

I tried code below to overcome the EOL error but it didnt work. I want to do it automatically not manually add backslashes as prompt is text which will change for input to an api. This made no difference
def escape_newline(string):
return string.replace("\n", "\\n")
prompt= scape_newline(prompt)

```
print (prompt)
```

This comes up with:
prompt = (f"xxxx
^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use triple strings instead of single ones. That allows for strings to take place over multiple lines :)

```
prompt = (f"""xxxx
xxxx
xxxxx
xxxx
xxxx""")
print(prompt)
```